# How can I programmatically get the theme name?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, is there a way to figure out what theme you are currently using in a module?  I need to get the name programmatically within the code of a module.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using the theme manager is the proper Drupal 8 way of getting information about your theme.

```
\Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()
```

*A general rule in drupal 8 is look for the manager (/handler) service.*

** Note: as [Neograph734](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/9921/neograph734) pointed out, `\Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()` will return the [active theme object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ActiveTheme.php/class/ActiveTheme/). If you want to get the theme machine-name then use `\Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()->getName()`

Comment: Note that the actual theme name can be derived from the ActiveTheme with `getName()`. So to get the theme name one would use `\Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme()->getName();`

Answer (score 6):

This will do it:

```
$config = \Drupal::config('system.theme');    
print $config->get('default');
```

You can always use drush to explore your available configs:

```
drush config-list
```

and

```
drush config-list system
```

gave me a list:

```
...
system.rss
system.site
system.theme.global
system.theme
...
```

and then I could check with the following:

```
drush cget system.theme.global
```

and

```
drush cget system.theme
```

to finally find out that it holds a `default` property that was what you asked for.

Comment: This answers returns the default theme.  The OP asked for the current theme, and the accepted answer returns current theme.  Normally it won't matter, but if there is a module that dynamically selects a theme depending on page/domain/user etc then the difference is important.

Comment: True, if there is a custom theme negotiator in play, the results will differ. If not, then the `getActiveTheme()` function will end up returning exactly the same:  `$this->configFactory->get('system.theme')->get('default')`

Answer (score 4):

1. if you want to get actual active theme name `administration theme` included Use :

```
 $activeThemeName = \Drupal::service('theme.manager')->getActiveTheme();
```

1. if you want your default selected theme `theme used in front` not 
   `admistartion theme` Use :

```
 $defaultThemeName = \Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('default');
```