# How to resolve the negotiated theme for any other user?

Tags: 8, theme-negotiation

I have found [How can I programmatically get the theme name?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203312/how-can-i-programmatically-get-the-theme-name), which works for the current user, but would I apply such logic to learn what theme another user would use?

I can get the active theme for current user and the default theme by using:

```
$my_theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();
$default_theme = \Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('default');
```

I was hoping there would be something like `\Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme($other_user);` to discover what theme another user would be using.

Is such a thing even possible and how?

UPDATE

To clear things up, I am attempting to figure out what theme was negotiated for a certain user. This could be the global default theme, but it could also be the theme that was negotiated based on a certain role, user selected theme, or any other contrib theme negotiator that might be in place.

So the better question would be, how can I discover what theme a user would be presented if he visits the site (no specific page)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, this type of functionality was built in in Drupal 6.

In Drupal 7 there was the ThemeKey module .

Unfortunately, as of this date ThemeKey is not yet ported to Drupal 8, however I think you can achieve pretty easy that functionality by using the user data object inside custom module.

In order get something from the user data object:

```
$data = \Drupal::service('user.data')->get('mymodule', \Drupal::currentUser()->id(), 'key');
```

In order to set something in the user data object:

```
\Drupal::service('user.data')->set('mymodule', \Drupal::currentUser()->id(), 'key', $value);
```

**Update:**

you can combine the code above with the solution posted here:

https://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/259/theme-negotiators-switch-theme-dynamically

where your negotiator will be called last by adding priority in the services.yml

you can implement the business logic inside the function the function determineActiveTheme. Combine this with hook_user_login where the information is stored inside users_data and you have a working solution (If I don't have a mistake somewhere).

Comment: Thanks, but it is a little more complicated, hence the question. Drupal 8 uses theme negotiators that may negotiate a theme based on an order or negotiators that each may or may not apply. So just checking for a theme key might not be enough as it might be overruled by a role based negotiator and so on. I was hoping to fetch the final theme after all these criteria.

Comment: @Neograph734 Indeed, but you need to provide context to those negotiators for them to do anything. What context do you want to provide? Just URL or something else too?

Comment: @Clive, I'd like to get the default theme for any other user (provide the user as context). If I have to provide a URL for that, it would probably be the home page.

Comment: What do you mean by "default" though, that wouldn't be covered  by this answer? Their default theme is either _the_ default theme, or the one they've chosen, right? Unless you want the result to be based on some context like current route, current device, etc, a la themekey. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Clive, I meant their negotiated theme; the theme they see when they access the site (not a particular page). This might be the default theme, might be what they have chosen, but can also be the theme that any other contrib negotiator might have put in between.